# ASP connection error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm getting an error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

My code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\App_Data\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True");

protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText =  "insert into User(name, status, type) values('"+txtName.Text+"', '"+txtStatus.Text+ "', '" + txtType.Text + "')";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Webform1.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Please read this before you start to write code that mixes button_click events with SqlCommand objects.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User` is reserved keyword in SQL, you should use square brackets.

Try this:

```
 cmd.CommandText =  "insert into [User](name, status, type) values('"+txtName.Text+"', '"+txtStatus.Text+ "', '" + txtType.Text + "')";
```

Comment: And happy sql injection

Comment: Please don't give an answer that gets someone on the sql-injection train from the get go.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: In fairness, the OP was already on the sql-injection train from the beginning.

Comment: Some questionable assumptions about unknown instances being of user input types. stick to the question in hand.

Comment: Fixing the problem of square brackets could be trivial. Letting the OP go away happy with code full of problems is a disservice and not at the level expectd by the answers on this site.